# How to handle exceptions thrown by keycloak in Java?

Tags: java, jersey, jetty, jersey-2.0, keycloak

I am using keycloak authentication with java. The keycloak java adapter throws exceptions in case of invalid tokens etc. Now, I want to catch these exceptions so that I can show custom message and do other stuffs. **In the below example I tried to catch exceptions by creating a filter but was unsuccessful.**

E.g.:

**DEBUG TRACE:**
In the following trace, `AuthentciatedActionHandler.isAuthorised` method throws exception in case of invalid token.

[image]

I thought that may be adding a filter with Priority(1) will introduce the filter somewhere in the stack and I can handle the exceptions thrown by keycloak in the filter. But as you can see, filter does not come in stack calls.

**(Although in case of valid request, AuthMasterFilter comes in stack trace)**

**My Jetty config:**

```
ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS | ServletContextHandler.SECURITY ); //keycloak
context.setContextPath("/");
context.addFilter(GzipFilter.class, "/*", EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class));
context.addFilter(AuthMasterFilter.class, "/*", EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST)); // filter to handle exceptions from keycloak

ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig(ImmutableSet.<Class<?>>builder().add(KeycloakRestService.class).build());        

context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new ServletContainer(resourceConfig)), "/*");
KeycloakJettyAuthenticator kcAuthenticator = ... // set up keycloak
ConstraintSecurityHandler securityHandler = new ConstraintSecurityHandler();
securityHandler.setAuthenticator(kcAuthenticator);
context.setSecurityHandler(securityHandler);
```

**AUTHMASTERFILTER.java:**

```
@Priority(1)
public class AuthMasterFilter implements Filter{

    @Override
    public void destroy() { }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest arg0, ServletResponse arg1, FilterChain arg2)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("Master called");        
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {}

}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the `AuthMasterFilter` after defining the security handler, instead of before?

Comment: @XtremeBiker No. Logically should that work? Let me give it a shot

Comment: @XtremeBiker No. Even adding it after security handler does not work

Comment: Authentication occurs before the request filter chain is even initiated (to satisfy requirements of the servlet security constraints).  There's no way to have a filter that is part of the request filter chain before security handling (or session handling, or content-encoding deflate / gzip handling, or any other feature that needs to operate outside of the request filter chain)

Comment: Hi did you found a solution to the problem?